# Customizing by myself Kendo UI Scheduler

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I need a specific functionality which is TimeLine View in Kendo UI scheduler
(http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/index.html)

Something like this:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html

This is something Kendo is planning for future releases but the problem is I need this right now. The slot in scheduler All day supports some of that functionality but there are a few changes necessary (the events cant dissapear if they are shorter than one day and snap functionality must be off).

Kendo is able to provide support only for the solutions that are now implemented.

Since most of the functionality is in .js scripts you download do you maybe know if its possible for me to modife them to get what I need ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the TimeLine view is not supported in Kendo UI Scheduler. Every interested in about this functionality can vote for it in the [opened uservoice discussion](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/4390720-implement-timeline-view-for-kendo-ui-scheduler).

Extending any of the existing views will not be sufficient as the TimeLine view has a different orientation. You can check the [Custom view](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-view) code library, which shows how to create a custom view. The rest of the job is to implement your own view, which looks like a TimeLine view.